# Reference to "bounds of Weil and Deligne"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, sieve-theory

In the this [paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9811185.pdf) by Friedlander and Iwaniec, it is said that they are "able to avoid much of the high-powered technology frequently used in modern analytic number theory such as the bounds of Weil and Deligne." What bounds are being referred to here?

Comment: Presumably, the bound resulting from Deligne's proof of the Riemann hypothesis for algebraic varieties over finite fields. That is, $\#X(\mathbb F_{q^n}) \leq \sum_r q^{nr/2} \dim H^r(X)$.

Comment: Sometimes one needs refinements of this bound, starting from the fact that for a connected variety of dimension $d$ the count is $q^d$ plus lower order terms.

Comment: Which section of the paper could use these bounds? Also, is there any reference which discusses this?

Comment: @NoamD.Elkies: geometrically connected.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first of these bounds was explicitly stated by Weil in the short paper

- André Weil, "On some exponential sums" (1948)

It depends on the Riemann hypothesis for curves over finite fields, which he had proved back in the early 40s, and shows that

$$|S(m,n;p)|\leq 2 \sqrt{p}$$

where $S(m,n;p)$ is the classic Kloosterman sum

$$S(m,n;p)=\sum_{\substack{{x (\mathrm{mod}\, p)} \\ (x,p)=1}} e\left(\frac{mx+nx^{-1}}{p}\right)$$

The second bound is due to Deligne, and holds for the more general hyper-Kloosterman sum, that is, sums of the form

$$K_n(p)=\sum_{\substack{{x_1,...,x_n (\mathrm{mod}\, p)} \\ x_1 \cdots x_n=1}} e\left(\frac{x_1+\cdots+x_n}{p}\right)$$

and the precise estimate is

$$|K_n(p)|\leq np^{(n-1)/2}$$

This one depends on the Riemann hypothesis for functions fields, which Deligne had proved on the famous paper

- Pierre Deligne, "La conjecture de Weil: I" (1974)

The applications to hyper-Kloosterman sum were worked out in detail in

- Pierre Deligne, "SGA 4½: Cohomologie étale" (1977)

particularly the Exposé 6, "Applications de la formule des traces aux sommes trigonométriques", section 7, "Sommes de Kloosterman généralisées".

It also important to mention the work of Katz on exponential sums, building directly on that of Deligne, particuarly the book

- Nicholas Katz "Gauss Sums, Kloosterman Sums, and Monodromy Groups" (1988)

Comment: Weil's paper is only for one-variable sums, which only depend on the Riemann Hypothesis for curves over finite fields, which he proved (so the bounds in his paper, in particular the one for Kloosterman sums, were indeed unconditional at that time.)   The bounds of Deligne are suitable (under certain conditions) for sums over two or more variables (e.g., hyper-Kloosterman sums in two or more variables).